# Windows Form not showing in design mode after changing the font of the form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I changed my form Font to Pak Nastaleeq (Its an Urdu font) of my widows application form, but after that my form is not show. its showing following result of the form in its design mode.

[image]

Please help me and tell me what should I do to get my form back as it was earlier.

Thanks

Comment: odds are you have a compile time error, correct it.
to get your form "back as it was earlier" use CTRL + Z numerous times or simply don't save your changes.

Comment: Close the project and open the form designer file in a text editor. Look up the line with the font name and remove it. Maybe first check what it looks like for a new WinForms application and change it to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Clean & Rebuild.
- Restart Visual Studio.
- Tools->Options->Productivity Power Tools->Automatic Brace Completion (Turn it off). Don't worry you can turn it on again.
- Make sure the `target platform` and `target mode either Debug/Release`.

Answer (score 0):

It is always to version your project as you make changes if you are using express. Son that you can then just go to the previous file.designer.cs file and copy the source and do the necessary changes. Just a tip.